# Debugging a hook function

Tags: buffers, debugging, hooks

I have this code:

```lisp
(add-hook
  'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
     (when (string-match "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)
       (face-remap-add-relative 'default :background "yellow"))))
```

and it should change the background color of the buffer where is `notes.org` file.

However, it doesn't work.

I have tried this as well:

```lisp
(add-hook
  'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
     (when (string-match "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)
       (set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "yellow"))))
```

But it is still not working.

The echo area says `if: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about trying:  `... (when (and (not (null buffer-file-name)) (string-match-p "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)) ...) ...`

Comment: The same error is popping up.

Comment: @lawlist Have you tried it for some file name in your emacs? Did it work? Did the backgound color change?

Comment: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (when (and (not (null buffer-file-name)) (string-match-p "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name)) (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:foreground "black" :background "yellow")))))`

Comment: @lawlist Please, add it as an answer so I can select it as a correct answer, because it seems to be working. Alghout, for some reason, I had to restart Spacemacs. It says in the error message something about tests and the code evaluated seemed to be old. Perhaps Spacemacs have some cache? Anyway, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Inasmuch as @Drew has been a mentor/teacher for the Emacs community, I would not feel comfortable writing up a competing answer in this situation.  If the answer needs any editing, then I'll leave that up to him to decide.  Your latest issue may have been due to the `org-mode-hook` storing prior attempts at solutions while you were debugging.  In addition, the working solution uses a list for the face specs -- whereas, your example omits the list.

Comment: @lawlist: `(not (null X))` is the same as `X`. ;-)

Comment: @lawlist: Please add your answer. It depends on what the question is really about. Is it about fixing OP's code or about answering how to debug such a problem. I guess OP should decide what question is really being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer provides a working solution to the underlying issue of the O.P., and contains a couple of suggestions made by @Drew in both his alternative answer and in a comment underneath the original question.  In terms of how to debug the issue posed by the O.P., please refer to the alternative answer by @Drew.

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (and buffer-file-name
                       (string-match-p "notes\\.org$" buffer-file-name))
              (face-remap-add-relative 'default
                                       '(:foreground "black" :background "yellow")))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just one important thing for future visitors. You have to restart Emacs - or at least in my case when using Spacemacs. For some reason just reloading the .spacemacs file via SPC f e R doesn't work. You have to restart or reopen Emacs. For example, if you change "yellow" to "blue" and only reload config it will stay like that even if you close the buffer and reopen it. But after closing and starting Emacs again it will change to blue ;)

Answer (score 1):

`buffer-file-name` is returning `nil`, and `string-match` expects (needs) a string instead. So `string-match` raised an error telling you that.

`buffer-file-name` is returning `nil` because the current buffer is not visiting a file. The buffer in which you've turned on Org mode is not a file buffer.  (E.g., it's a buffer such as `*scratch*`, which is not associated with a file.)

(Also, in general, if you're not going to use the `match-data` then you should use `string-match-p`, not `string-match`, as it's more efficient.)

For debugging, do this: `M-x set-variable RET debug-on-error RET t RET`.  That shows you a backtrace, which lets you know which function raised the error and shows you the context/history of the evaluation.

Clearly you hadn't understood that the problem wasn't reported by function `string-match`. You thought it had something to do with your code about faces. Use non-`nil` `debug-on-error` to help with this kind of thing. You can customize it to `t`, so it's on by default: `M-x customize-option RET debug-on-error t`.

Comment: I have this code inside `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()` in `.spacemacs` file and I am refreshing/reloading this file while being inside by pressing `SPC f e R` and then this error shows up in the minibuffer. So, I want the background color to change only for `notes.org` and I need to compare it somehow with the current buffer name. According to you the condition is bad because the buffername returns nil and the name `"notes\\.org$"` is string => so the comparison fails and the function stops. Right? So, how to make it "not stop" and continue working?

Comment: Could you help with my code? Perhaps try it in your config for some file if the backgroudn color can be changed like this or not. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This site isn't really about fix-my-code, in some general way. The hook is apparently being invoked while a non-file buffer is current. Why that is so is up to you to investigate. If it's enough to just make it a no-op when a non-file is current then that fixes your problem. If not, figure out which buffer is current when the problem arises, and why that's so. In general, if invoking a hook function you need to be aware of, or in control of, which buffer is current.